# cohomology homomorphism between grassmannians induced by inclusion

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, characteristic-classes

Let $i:G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)\to G_k(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ be inclusion of grassmannians.

Then

$H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^\infty);\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_k]$.

$ H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^n);\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_k]/(\bar w_{n-k+1},\bar w_{n-k+2},\cdots,\bar w_{n})$.

(c.f. An additive basis for the cohomology of real Grassmannians, Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume 1474, 1991, pp 231-234. )

Let $i^*:  H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^\infty);\mathbb{Z}_2)\to
 H^*(G_k(\mathbb{R}^n);\mathbb{Z}_2)$
 be the induced homomorphism in cohomology.

Is $i^*$ the quotient map $q:  \mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_k]\to
\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_k]/(\bar w_{n-k+1},\bar w_{n-k+2},\cdots,\bar w_{n})$?

Comment: Yes. But you're not going to be able to prove it abstractly like that, you need to go back to how you computed these cohomology rings.

Comment: Dear Prof. Najib Idrissi, I am not clear how we compute these cohomologies. Could you explain more or give some references? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's done in Milnor and Stasheff, *Characteristic classes*; the $w_k$ are called the Stiefel-Whitney classes, if you don't know what to look for. Maybe also in Bott and Tu, *Differential forms in algebraic topology* but I'm less sure. (And I'm no prof :p)